# customized circular progress bar is not working android

Tags: android, progress-bar, custom-controls

I download this code from internet (in the end I set the link)

for customize the color circular progress bar

But the circular progress bar is not rotating
Am I missing something?
the progress bar is "static"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="true"
            android:thicknessRatio="14.0">

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorBlanco"
                android:endColor="@color/colorBlanco"
                android:centerColor="@color/colorBlanco"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="270" >
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:thicknessRatio="14.0">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:toDegrees="360"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/colorAzul"
                    android:endColor="@color/colorAzul"
                    android:centerColor="@color/colorAzul"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

this code has my launcher

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progress="80"
    android:max="100"
    android:secondaryProgress="100"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo_app_launcher"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar" />
```

[Horizontal and Circular Progress Bar in Android](http://www.geeks.gallery/horizontal-and-circular-progress-bar-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Set `progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable()` to any drawable file it
will replace your moving loader to the defined moving image.

Comment: is it programatically? or in xml?

Comment: U need to set programmatic in java code before u show progress bar